# How can I check if event is complete in google calendar api

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

I am setting up goals in the Google calendar and I want to check with the google-calendar-api if they are completed or not.

So I am following the Google api quickstart instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/python). None of the returned event properties seem to refer to fact that they are completed or not.

My code after credentials looks like this:

```
service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)
events_result = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', timeMin=now,
                                      maxResults=10, singleEvents=True,
                                      orderBy='startTime').execute()
events = events_result.get('items', [])
```

Result is a list containing dictionaries with the following keys:

```
{'kind',
'etag',
'id',
'status',
'htmlLink',
'created',
'updated',
'summary',
'description',
'creator,
'organizer',
'start': {'dateTime','timeZone'},
'end': {'dateTime','timeZone'},
'iCalUID',
'sequence',
'attendees': [{'email','self','responseStatus'}],
'privateCopy': True,
'reminders': {'useDefault'}}
```

None of the keys seem to answer the  question whether the event is completed or not. Completed/uncomplete eTags for the same goal have different eTags, but different goals have different eTags as well.

Comment: Having the same issue. I cannot find how to tell if a Reminder is completed (whether it was created from goals or not)

Answer (score 0):

As you said, there is no attribute to indicate whether an event is completed or not. A workaround to check this is to get the “end” attribute and, inside this, get the datetime attribute, and compare the value with the current time:

Also be aware that if the time zone where the script is running is not the same as the event timezone, there will be a discrepancy. To prevent this, you can use the date and the offset given in the string end date you got from the event (It’s in the ISO 8601 standard format [1], i.e: “2015-05-29T02:00:00+02:00”) to obtain the UTC time and compare this with the current UTC time. Check out how to work with dates and timezones in Python [2].

Here is the your code tweaked and successfully tested:

```
import datetime

service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)
events_result = service.events().list(calendarId='primary',
                                      maxResults=10, singleEvents=True,
                                      orderBy='startTime').execute()
events = events_result.get('items', [])

for event in events:
    eventEndStr = event['end']['dateTime']

    #Date section of the string
    dateStr = eventEndStr[:19]

    #Offset section of the string
    offsetStr = eventEndStr[19:]
    offsetHours = int(offsetStr[1:3])
    offsetMinutes = int(offsetStr[4:])
    offsetSign = offsetStr[:1]

    #Current date in UTC
    currentTime = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

    #Get end date in local time and offset
    endDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(dateStr, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
    offset = datetime.timedelta(hours=offsetHours, minutes=offsetMinutes)

    #Condition to obtain the end date in UTC
    if offsetSign == "+":
        endDate = endDate - offset
    else:
        endDate = endDate + offset

    #Condition to check if the event is over
    if (currentTime > endDate):
        print('This event is over')
    else:
        print('This event is not over')
```

[1] https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt

[2] https://stackabuse.com/converting-strings-to-datetime-in-python/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I probably didn't explain my question clearly enough. In google calendar you can set up goals/tasks, that you can mark as completed (irregardless that the due date is over or not). I want to use google calendar API to get the state of said goals (completed or not).